# IA32 - How to see the arguments for a call to sscanf()?

Tags: c, x86, gdb, scanf

I am a CS student struggling to learn Assembly, specifically IA-32.  I'm working on debugging a program in GDB, and in the code, I see a call to sscanf(), line `program+78`:

```
...lots more code here...
x0x8049564 <program+59>    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
x0x8049568 <program+63>    movl   $0x804a79f,0x4(%esp)
x0x8049570 <program+71>    movl   $0x804d8f0,(%esp)
x0x8049577 <program+78>    call   0x80488d0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
...lots more code here...
```

As any good C programmer knows, sscanf() looks like this:

```
int sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)
```

I'm guessing that lines `program+59` through `program+71` are setting up the pointers to the strings which are fed into sscanf().  I'm also pretty sure that after the function returns, `%eax` is holding the number of items scanned.

Trouble is, I need to look at those "input strings" before sscanf() is called.  And for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it.  Maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like memory addresses `$0x804a79f` and `$0x804d8f0` must point to strings, essentially my input strings for sscanf().  Those pointers are loaded into an array based off register `%esp`.  But I can't figure out how to look at the original strings nor the array.  Here's my clumsy attempts to stumble upon the correct syntax:

```
(gdb) x/sb $esp
0xffffd310:  "\360\330\004\b\237\247\...long string of numbers here...
(gdb) x/sb ($esp + 0x4)
0xffffd314:  "\237\247\004\b4\323\...long string of numbers here...
(gdb) p *(int*) $esp
$1 = 134535408
(gdb) x/sb $0x804a79f
Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) p *(int*) $0x804a79f
Invalid cast.
(gdb) p *(int*) $0x804d8f0
Invalid cast.
```

I totally admit, I'm just blindly stabbing for a solution.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you are trying to view the strings before `scanf()` is called, then it is no wonder that you get nothing meaningful: both buffers are most probably filled with garbage. To view the contents of the format string, execute `x/sb 0x804d8f0` while standing on, say, `0x8049577`. And yes, there\`s no need to put `$` before a constant when doing `x/sb`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb Ah, yes, you're totally right.  I don't know why I had it lodged in my head that you needed the $ before everything.  I can see the input strings now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p  *(int*) 0x804d8f0` (without the `$`) should work, if you want the first 4 bytes of the format-string as a little-endian integer, printed in decimal.  gdb uses C-like syntax even when debugging asm.

Probably more useful: `p (char*) 0x804a79f`.  Since it's a char*, gdb will print the address, but also the null-terminated C string starting at that address.

---

In gdb syntax, the convention is `$register_name` to use the value of a register in an expression.

So you could do `p *(char**) ($esp+4)`, if I have the syntax correct.  It's a char* stored in memory (on the stack), so you need to dereference `($esp+4)` to get the `char *fmt` function arg that the caller has stored before the CALL instruction.

---

The `$` prefix in the asm output is because that's what distinguishes an immediate constant operand from using the number as an address for a memory operand.  i.e. `movl  0x804a79f, %eax` would load 32 bits from that address into eax.  (I changed the destination to a register, because x86 doesn't support having two explicit memory operands to the same instruction.)

This is an AT&T syntax thing, the same thing that NASM syntax uses square brackets (or their absence) for.  Nothing to do with gdb's command syntax.

You can use `set disassembly-flavor intel` in gdb to disassemble in GNU-flavoured Intel syntax.  (I put that in my `~/.gdbinit`).  Choose whichever asm syntax you're already partly familiar with, but keep in mind that Intel's x86 manuals all use Intel syntax (destination operand first).  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to manuals, and a section at the bottom on using gdb for asm.

Comment: Thanks for this, your entire reply gets copied into my notes.  Its helpful yet frustrating that GDB adopts C-like syntax, but this gives me a better handle on how to drill in on the data I want.  What I'd love to see if a procedure...  You know, look inside register EAX, see an int or a pointer to something.  If its a pointer, determine if its a pointer to a string?  If so, use "x/sb $eax"  If not, use p *(int*)$eax, etc.  That will take time to develop.  But you've got me on my way.  THanks!!!

Comment: @pete: For programs that don't use a huge amount of memory, the hex value of pointers is fairly recognizable, because they're in a couple ranges: stack addresses, BSS addresses, data segment addresses, ROdata (text segment) addresses.  Dynamically-allocated (malloc) addresses are usually very near the BSS, for small allocations that used `brk()`, but big allocations that use mmap can be anywhere.  (But still, they often look pointer-ish, since most numbers in most programs are small-magnitude positive or negative.) x86-64 makes this easier, because there's more always-the-same bits in pointers